# Iteration in R, weird result with for-loop

Tags: r, algorithm, for-loop, iteration

I'm writing some code in R in order to determine an optimal estimator for `ai` given any tolerance. So far, I've come up with this:

```
iter<- function (ai, k, tolerance){
  at = ai*(1-ai^2*R[k]^ai*(log(R[k]))^2/(1-R[k]^ai)^2)/
(1 - (ai^2*R[k]^ai*(log(R[k]))^2)/(1-R[k]^ai)^2 + ai*(H(k) 
- 1/ai - R[k]^ai*log(R[k])/(1-R[k]^ai)))
  while((at-ai) > tolerance) {
    ai = at
    at = ai*(1-ai^2*R[k]^ai*(log(R[k]))^2/(1-R[k]^ai)^2)/
(1 - (ai^2*R[k]^ai*(log(R[k]))^2)/(1-R[k]^ai)^2 + ai*(H(k) 
- 1/ai - R[k]^ai*log(R[k])/(1-R[k]^ai)))
    a0 = at
  }
  return(at)
}

x<- iter(ai = H(k), k, tolerance = 0.000001)
```

where `R` and `H` are known variables for every `k` and also an initial estimator for `ai` is known, namely `H(k)`. This code works fine for any value of `k`, for example,

```
x<- iter(ai = H(k), 21, tolerance = 0.000001)
```

gives a good result. However, my problem is, that when I try to embed this in a for-loop (I actually want a vector `x[k]` where every iteration for `k` is calculated), i.e. :

```
for (k in seq (along = 1: (n-1)){
x<- iter(ai = H(k), 21, tolerance = 0.000001)
}
```

this code doesn't give me a vector, but instead it gives one value for `x`. That doesn't make much sense to me, as I'm trying to assign a value to `x` for every possible `k`. What am I missing here?

As always, any help would be dearly appreciated.

Comment: `x` gets overwritten each iteration. Do you see it? Allocate it properly and assign the result to a single element of `x`.

Comment: Dear downvoter, what is the reason for your downvote? Please tell me, so that I can adjust my questions in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want a vector, `x` should be a vector.

```
x<-numeric(n-1)
for (k in seq (along = 1: (n-1)){
    x[k]<- iter(ai = H(k), 21, tolerance = 0.000001)
}
```